# How to get JSON objects from web service response

Tags: html, json, web-services, url, object

I am very new to use web services, javascript, JSON technologies and I need to use a URL to get some data to use in my HTML file.

The url that I am trying to get value of is something like [this](http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=key&Cmd=PoiSearch&Typ=JSON&Latitude=30&Longitude=30&Radius=10000&Brand=SomeBrand&Keyword=).

the result of this url in browser is like below:

```
{
  "transactionid": "asdf", 
  "status": 0,
  "poilist": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "some company",
      "address": "address",
      "latitude": 333333,
      "longitude": 333333,
      "distance": 4869
    },
    {
      .... // lots of similar nodes to above
    }
}
```

I need to get some properties of poilist list such as longitude, latitude etc. and use them in my HTML file which includes only Javascript and HTML codes.

I made some research on internet but couldn't find a appropriate example for my situation. I don't know where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to it this way:

```
var url = 'http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=key&Cmd=PoiSearch&Typ=JSON&Latitude=30&Longitude=30&Radius=10000&Brand=SomeBrand&Keyword=';

$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,

        // the name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
        jsonp: "callback",

        // tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",



        // work with the response
        success: function (response) {
            //response is an object. use it here
            console.log(response); // server response
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hlapidez/sm64g/

Comment: Hi Hank, Thank you so much for the reply. That was what I've been looking for. jsfiddle is a very nice site. I didn't know about it..

Comment: jsfiddle is nice when quickly trying something out.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with jQuery, specificaly with `jQuery.getJSON()`. Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

If you haven't used jQuery and don't know how to use it. I would look at here [first](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Very basic example of loading the data and showing them in console would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = ""; //enter an url here

    $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Hope this helps for u.

    Here poilist is an JsonArray.
            So u have to iterate poilist and get poilist properties

            javascript example

                var response = "{ "transactionid": "asdf", "status": 0, "poilist": [ { "id": 123, "name": "some company", "address": "address", "latitude": 333333, "longitude": 333333, "distance": 4869 },... ";

                var poiList = response.poilist;
                for(var i=0;i<poiList.length;i++){
                  var name = poiList[i].name;
                  var id= poiList[i].id;
                  var lat = poiList[i].latitutde;
                  var long = poiList[i].longitude;
                  console.log(lat);
                  console.log(long);
                }

        This code will print all properties of poilist in browser's console.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I want to have an object like you write above in your code named response but dont wat to copy and paste all of the JSONArray to my HTML file. Is there any way to get the full JSONArray giving the url?

Comment: Are u using Ajax to get data from server?

Comment: Actually the problem is that, I dont know what to use, or how to do. I dont know using Ajax as well.

Comment: 1. Load Jquery.js and some of our freinds posted some code samples below on how to make ajax call. please refer that store the same in response variable as i mentioned in answer